# Is it secure to send a php value in a link

Tags: php, html, security

I have a dynamic page where it should take data from a db. So the approach I thought of was to create the dynamic page with this php code at the top

```
<?php $pid = $_GET["pid"]; ?>
```

Then later in the file it connects to the database and shows the correct content according to the page ID ($pid). So on the home page, I want to add the links to display the correct pages. For example, the data for the "Advertise" page is saved in the database in the row where the pid is 100. So I added the link to the "Advertise" page on the homepage like this:

```
<a href="http://site/page.php?pid=100">Advertise</a></li>
```

So my question is, anyone can see the value that's send on the link and play around by changing the pid. Is there an easy way to mask this value, or a safer method to send the value to the `page.php`?

Comment: Do you mean like the way SO (and sites over internet) showing member page and all of its data?

Comment: It's super easy for a) bots to scrape all your pages and b) changing the URL is super easy for any user to do. What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @Chay22, for example, the Heading and Content paragraph details are stored in a db. So when the page loads, the page gets the heading and content from the relevant fields in the db and displays on the page.

Comment: @Laurel, safe in the sense, a way the user doesn't see the value that's passed with the link

Comment: @YohanBlake Really? Not even if they look up a little, to the address bar? What if they drag the link? More experienced haxxors will just look at the source code.

Comment: @Laurel, I'm not sure. I'm just asking if it can be a threat to the site if the value I send is visible publicly

Comment: @YohanBlake How does [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4749489) showing your data? Doesn't it `$_GET` with URL prettied?

Comment: @Chay22, good point. So I'm guessing that's safe then. Thanks :)

Comment: @YohanBlake Any user input can be dangerous depending on what your code does with it. Like in a ReDOS.

Comment: @Laurel, my code only queries the db table for a Heading and a Content paragraph and displays it on the page. FYI, the db connection details (username, password) is included in the page.php too. Can hackers access those data just from the GET variable and value?

Comment: @YohanBlake see my answer.  As for your DB credentials, that's a separate question.

Comment: @YohanBlake it's all about how you show it, how you connect to db, how you fetch the data. Both POST or GET will remain risky depend on your code.

Comment: @YohanBlake consider asking on [Info Sec](http://security.stackexchange.com/) for hardcore security tips.

Comment: @Laurel - The Info Sec SE is going to be significantly over the head of the OP. If you have specific links to questions on that SE, please provide those instead.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Maybe if I knew PHP a little better. I have a little trouble knowing what's relevant or not.

Comment: Best article concerning your problem: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 2):

The general concept you're looking for is [Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control).  You have a **resource** (in this case, a page and its content), and you want to control **who** can access it (users, groups, etc), and probably **how** they can access it as well (for example, read-only, read-and-write, write-but-only-on-the-first-Monday-of-the-month, etc).

### Defining the problem

The first thing you need to decide is which resources you need access control for, and which you don't.  It sounds to me like some of these pages are supposed to be "public access" (thus they are listed on some kind of index page), while others are supposed to be restricted in some way.

Secondly, you need to come up with an **access policy** - this can be informally described for a small project, but larger projects usually have some structured system for defining this policy.  **For each resource**, your policy should answer questions like:

- Do you have some kind of user account system, and you only want account holders (or certain types of account holders) to access it?  Or, are you going to send links to email addresses, and want to limit access to just those people who have the link?
- What kind of access should each user have?  Read-only?  Should they be able to change the content as well (if your system supports that)?
- Are there any other types of restrictions on a users' access?  Group membership?  Do they need to pay before they get access?  Are they only allowed access at specific times?

### Implementing your policy

Once you've answered these questions, you can start to think about implementation.  As it stands, I think you are mixing up access control with **identification**.  Your `pid` *identifies* a page (page 100, for example), but it doesn't do anything to limit access.  If your pages are identified with a predictable numbering scheme, anyone can easily modify the number in the request (this is true for both `GET` requests, such as when you type a URL into an address bar, and `POST` requests, such as when you submit a form).

To securely control access there needs to be a **key**, usually a string that is very difficult to guess, which is required before access is granted.  In very simple systems, it is perfectly fine for this key to be directly inserted in the URL, *provided you can still keep the key secret from unauthorized users*.  This is exactly how Google Drive's "get a link to share" feature works.  More complex systems will use either a server-side session or an API key to control access - but in the end, it's still a secret, difficult-to-guess string that the client (user or user's browser) sends to the server along with their request for the resource.

You can think of identification like your street address, which uniquely identifies your house but is not, and is not meant to be, secret.  Access control is the key to your house.  Only you and the people you've given a key to can actually get inside your house.  If your lock is high quality, it will be difficult to pick the lock.

### Bringing it together

Writing code is easy, designing software is hard.  Before you can determine the solution best for you, you need to think ahead about the ramifications of what you decide.  For example, do you anticipate needing to "change the keys" to these pages in the future?  If so, you'll have to give your authorized users (the ones that are still supposed to have access) the new key when that happens.  A user-account system decouples page access control from page identification, so you can remove one user's access without affecting everyone else.

On the other hand, you also need to think about the nature of your audience.  Maybe your users don't want to have to make accounts?  This is something that is going to be very specific to your audience.

I get the sense that you're still fairly new to web development, and that you're learning on your own.  The hardest part of learning on one's own is "learning what to learn" - Stack Overflow is too specific, and textbooks are too general.  So, I'm going to leave you with a short glossary of concepts that seem most relevant to your current problem:

- [Access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control).  This is the name of the general problem that you're trying to solve with this question.
- [Secrecy vs obscurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44096/74909).  When it comes to security, secrecy == good, obscurity == bad.
- [Web content management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system).  You've probably heard of Wordpress, but there are tons of others.  I'm not sure what your system is supposed to do, but a content management system might solve these problems for you.
- [Reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).  Good in the classroom, bad in the real world.
- [How does HTTP work](http://www.silicon-press.com/briefs/brief.http/brief.pdf).  Short but to the point.  A **lot** of questions I see on SO stem from a fundamental misunderstanding of how websites actually work.  A website isn't so much a single piece of software, as a conversation between two players - the client (e.g. the user and their browser), and the server.  The client can only say something to the server via a **request**, and the server can only say something to the client via a **response**.  Usually, this conversation consists of the client asking for some resource (an HTML web page, a Javascript file, etc), to which the server responds.  The server can either say "here you go, I got it for you", or respond with some kind of error ("I can't find it", "you're not allowed to see that", "I'm too busy right now", "I'm not working properly right now", etc).
- [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).  Something I wish I had found when I *first* started learning web development and PHP, not seven years later ;-)

Comment: A ([properly calculated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)) GUID in place of an incrementing primary key in the URL is the appropriate recommendation, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on what he is trying to do.  A random GUID in the URL is fine for very simple access control, but once you are controlling access to many different resources, it becomes easier to manage with either server-side sessions or some kind of cookie/local storage-based access token.  They're all equivalent in the end - a long, hard-to-guess string.  It's just a question of how that string gets passed to the server with each request.

Comment: You're confusing too many issues in your answer. I said a GUID is more appropriate in place of a primary-key auto-incrementing value, not that it's "securing" anything other than brute-force guessing the other rows on the predicate table of whatever query/ies it's feeding and responding  with other (potentially mal-access-controlled) rows that were unintentionally left available. Relying on GUIDs for access control and permissions is security-by-obscurity, which is no security at all.

Comment: The problem is that SO's question is ill-defined, and there are a lot of misconceptions bleeding through about how websites actually work.  So in order to give any meaningful recommendations, I need to first make sure he's understanding the underlying problem.

Comment: I agree, the OP has a newbish and short-sighted view of what they're doing. I don't have any good links to good information at that level, unfortunately. The question should probably be closed as unclear.

Comment: What I want is not access control. It is going to be all public. I just want a way to maybe hide the values after the `?` after the link. I'm simply sending a value from the home page to page.php where in page.php, the db is queried using the `pid` received from the home page. What's unclear in my question?

Comment: Hide it for cosmetic effect?  No matter what you do, you're going to need the client to send *some* kind of identifier to the server, and there is *always* a way to see the information sent.  If not in the address bar, then in the browser console or through some lower level process.  If you just want it to look nicer, that's a different matter.  URL rewriting would solve that.

Comment: I would also ask - if all content is truly public, then what is the purpose of hiding the `pid` in the URL?  Can you give me an example of what type of behavior you are trying to prevent?

Answer (score 1):

It is always safer to $_POST when you can, but if you have to use something in the query string, it is safer to use a hash or GUID rather than something that is so obviously an auto-incremental value. It makes it harder to guess what the IDs would be. There are other ways values can be past between pages ($_SESSIONs, cookies etc), but it is really about what you want to achieve.

Comment: In what context is it ["safer" to use POST instead of GET](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)? Secure, no, it's not any more difficult to make a POST request than a GET (or using COOKIE) if someone is round-robin pulling data by ID requests. A hash can also be guessed, real GUIDs are the way to go to block specifically the scenario you're describing. And I'm guessing a SESSION isn't ideal for a URL link.

Comment: so hashing before sending the value and de-hashing(if that's the correct term) can be more secure, right?

Comment: Nee, *block*, *make more difficult*.

Answer (score 0):

Sending it to php is not an issue, should be fine.

What php does with it afterwards... that's how you secure.

First thing I'd do is make sure it's an integer.

```
$pid=(is_int($_GET['pid']))? $_GET['pid'] : 1; //1 is the default pid, change this to whatever you want.
```

Now that you know you're dealing with an integer, use $pid after that and you should be good to go.